# wget Download multiple files from multiple URLs with multiple parts

Tags: windows, batch-file, download, wget

Complete newbie here so apologies in advance.

Basically, I am trying to automate as much of my process as possible. I want to be able to download a streaming video that is split into different .ts parts (around 150 of them).

For some reason, using the {0..150} function to loop through the parts isn't working for me, as it interprets the string as part of the URL, returning a Not found error. (Could it be that I'm running wget through Windows cmd?) Dug around a bit and was able to work out a script that successfully downloads the video files:

```
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 @echo off
 set directory=https://URLstring/playlist
 for /l %%x in (0, 1, 150) do (
    set tsNum=%%x
    set num=%directory%!tsNum!
    set ts=.ts
    set file=!num!!ts!
    wget !file!
 )
```

However, since there are 10 of these videos (each split into its own 150 parts) uploaded each week, I would like to be able to pull the 10 URLs from a .txt list.

I read up about the -i function for wget, but either I'm getting the syntax wrong, or I can't figure out a way to merge the 2 scripts.

Anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: No, you would not be able to use the wget -i option with the FOR /L command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read the urls from a file into the directory variable instead of hardcoding the directory variable then you could change your script like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "" %%a in (directory.txt) do (
    set directory=%%a
    for /l %%x in (0, 1, 150) do (
        set tsNum=%%x
        set num=!directory!!tsNum!
        set ts=.ts
        set file=!num!!ts!
        echo wget !file!
    )
)
```

If you want to read the number of parts from the file as well you can have each line in the file be the url and number of parts separated by space or tab (which is ok because urls don't contain spaces and tabs) and then change your script like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (directory.txt) do (
    set directory=%%a
    set parts=%%b
    for /l %%x in (0, 1, !parts!) do (
        set tsNum=%%x
        set num=!directory!!tsNum!
        set ts=.ts
        set file=!num!!ts!
        echo wget !file!
    )
)
```

Like @Squashman said, there is no reason to store the values in environment variables at all - you can just use the for loop variables directly like this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (directory.txt) do (
    for /l %%x in (0, 1, %%b) do (
        echo wget %%a%%x.ts
    )
)
```

this is the directory.txt I used for testing:

```
https://URLstring1/playlist 2
https://URLstring2/playlist 3
https://URLstring3/playlist 4
```

The first value I used on each line is the URL and the second is the number of parts.

Comment: Why use delayed expansion? You could just do `echo %%a%%x.ts`

Comment: I did it because the OP did it - I made the minimum number of changes to the OP's code so that it would be obvious what had changed.  But you are right: you don't need any variables other than the ones from the for loops.

Comment: Admittedly I'm not quite sure what delayed expansion's purpose is. I made some changes to a code I found in order to better fit my situation and left it there, since I had no idea if it was necessary or not.

Comment: @LPMA The purpose of the delayed expansion is that by default every environment variable (not for loop variables) is set to its final value when the line of code is read from the batch file - which doesn't work for a for loop because you want different values during every iteration.  What Squashman was saying is you don't need any of those environment variables anyway - you could just use the for loop variables directly (the only reason to have them is to echo them to the screen for debugging purposes)  I will edit the answer.

Comment: New code works perfectly. Is there a reason for leaving the echo command on the last line, which generates the list of files to get but doesn't actually make wget to download them?

Comment: @LPMA Sorry.  When I was testing I didn't actually want to retrieve the files.